# Define and validate combinations of elements

Tags: java, regex

How could I best define a set of desired combinations between elements of a given set, like S={A,B,C} and validate given combinations to be valid.

**Example:**

```
Element Set: S={A,B,C}
Set of valid combinations: C={ (A), (A,B), (A,C), (A,A) }
```

**Problem with RegEx:**

The problem I found when trying to use a regular expression like

```
(^A[ABC]{0,1}$)
```

is the usage of the separator (comma). This expression only matches words (combinations) of the form :

```
A
AA
AB
AC
```

Though, using the separator is necessary to distinguish words when working with an element set of say S={A, AA}. However Implementing the separator would overcomplicate the expression so that it is hard to produce and to read afterwards.

One could probably implement a special language for that but maybe there is another more simple way to do this ?

Comment: How about you remove the comma (should there be one) before you pass the string to the regular expression?

Comment: @reto: I need the comma to distinguish e.g. A,A and AA

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern:

```
String input = "C={ (A), (A,B), (A,C), (A,A) }";
                          //| starts with "A"
                             //|May be followed by comma, and A or B or C
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("A(,\\s?([ABC],?\\s?)+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
A
A,B
A,C
A,A
```

This will also work with patterns like `(A, ABC)`.

As the separator is part of the regular expression, it's trivial to add.

If you have multiple separators, you can use a character class instead (so `,` may become `[,./]` if you use `.` and `/` as well.

If you have hierarchical data representation you need to parse, it's likely that regular expressions are not what you're looking for though.

Comment: what about C={ (A), (A, AA) } ?

Comment: @user1240076 added optional whitespace in my pattern - see edit.